# use of 'ever' in imperative sentences

Tags: adverbs

What is the difference between the two?

> Don't do that.
>   Don't ever do that.

Does this ask one not to do something that they do repeatedly?

Answer (score 2):

> Don't do that

is a simple sentence advising that you should not do that.

Adding 'ever' puts more emphasis or stress. It is, *as compared to the previous one*, is considered more serious. And, it denotes that you shouldn't do that even in future.

Here, 'ever' is for future and not the past. So, there's no question of having done it *repeatedly.*

Comment: Yes, "ever" adds stress but it does have meaning as well, to imply "not now or anytime in the future"

Comment: @Andrew ah..missed that *obvious* note! Added!

Comment: 'ever' for future, sounds like 'never'

Comment: Yes, *don't ever do that = never do that* @马化腾